# How to count occurances of phrase in grep, ignoring case?

Tags: shell, grep, wc

I need to search for a name `nicolas bomber` with `grep`. Name can also be `NiCoLaS BomBer`. I need to run a `.sh` file which display the number of occurrences of that name.

The command I made is this one:

```
grep -i "Nicolas \s*Bomber" annuaire | wc -l
```

but it does't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: how exactly is it going wrong? the command you gave should work as expected.. you can also use `grep -ioc "Nicolas \s*Bomber" annuaire` to avoid using another command..

Comment: probably you have multiple occurrence of pattern in same line? in that case `-io` in your original command would have solved that issue

Comment: I have problems if the name is NiColAs and if there are more than one space between the first name and the second.

Comment: the `-i` option would take care of `NiColAs` and ` \s*` should take care of `more than one space between the first name and the second`.. probably something else is wrong here? can you paste sample input file and output you get when you run `grep -io "Nicolas \s*Bomber" annuaire | wc -l`?

Comment: could be split across two lines...

Comment: @JohnnyOnPc Please add example input and output, preferably the one that shows edge cases.

Comment: (Cont’d) …  So, if *this* question (the above) isn’t a duplicate of one of those other (clearer) questions, I don’t know what it is asking.  Either way, it doesn’t seem to add any value to the site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

grep's `-o` will only output the matches, ignoring lines; `wc` can count them:

```
grep -io "nicolas bomber" annuaire | wc -l
```

or simply,

```
grep -ioc "nicolas bomber" annuaire
```

As you commented, you can match any number of whitespaces coming in between the words, using `-z` option,

```
grep -iz "nicolas[[:space:]]*bomber" annuaire | wc -l
```

From `man grep`

```
-i, --ignore-case
    Ignore case distinctions in both the PATTERN and the input files.  (-i is specified by POSIX.)    

-o, --only-matching
    Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

-c, --count
    Suppress  normal  output;  instead  print  a  count  of  matching  lines  for each input file.
```

Alternatively, if you want to search the string in specific file extension, for example say all `*.txt` files, you can use:

```
grep -R --include='*.txt' -ioc "nicolas bomber" .
```

Comment: if I use the wc -l command it displays the result with a tab , which I do not need. and the -z command is not recognized, I use unix.

Comment: can you please show your file with exact patterns ? [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/296080/edit) your post and paste it rather than extending conversation here.

Comment: The file has 8000 lines and i cant save it online , any suggestions how should i put it?

Comment: nicolas Bomber 424242-4242 bomber@42staff.fr

Comment: @JohnnyOnPc post sample 5-10 lines and paste here

Comment: @JohnnyOnPc and also post your expected output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42532/discussion-between-rahul-and-johnnyonpc).

Comment: https://ideone.com/oPu5jz and the output is '2' without the quotes.

Comment: please click on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42532/discussion-between-rahul-and-johnnyonpc)

Comment: You probably want `[[:space:]]+` (at least 1 occurrence) rather than `[[:space:]]*` (at least 0 occurrences) in there.

Comment: (1) If the question is about strings / patterns occurring multiple times on the same line, then the question should say so.   (2) `grep -oc` gives the same result as `grep -c` — it does ***not*** give the same result as ``grep -o | wc -l``.